# Script automatically generated in my <head> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, malware

A script has been appearing in the end of my  tag. It was generated in ALL files.

This caused my site to be blocked as it was treated as malware. Please help!

Comment: Blocked by whom, and where did this script come from?  You might want to include some more information and specifics, then when you have, placing it on [webmasters.se].

Comment: This is not a question for SO. In it's current form it's not a question for anywhere. Think about how someone who might help will do so, based on what you have posted.

Comment: It really belongs on [webmasters.se], if more info becomes available.

Comment: It's not a question at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry, but this script isn't being automatically generated.  You have been hacked, my friend.

This happened to one of my test web host accounts once, and with a bit of [google-fu](https://www.google.com/#q=site+hack+ads+inserted+into+my+webpage) I learned that it's a fairly common result of the account having been hacked or otherwise compromised.

In my case, it was ads.  In your case, it sounds like whomever got access to your site is using it to distribute some nasty stuff.

You should consult your web hosting company about what you should do and what they can do to help, but at the very least you should:

- Take your site down **immediately**.  Stop serving as a malware distribution hub.  You're almost certainly losing more visitors by being on the naughty list than you are by having the site return 404s for a while.
- Find the source of the intrusion and fix it so it doesn't happen again.  Your most likely attack vector is a script/module/other component that bears a known exploit.  Your web host may be able to help you here.
- Change all of your account passwords associated with that website, including any shell, ftp, database, email, and anything else you have set up.  Assume these passwords are in someone's list now.
- For that matter, start using a password manager if you aren't already; that's probably what got you in trouble.  Sharing passwords between sites is a good way to get owned.
- Start looking for a backup that doesn't have the malicious script tag additions and restore to it.
- Follow the links in the malware warnings to get your site off the lists once you've fixed the problem.

Good luck!

Comment: @umopepisdb Hi! Thanks for the list of advice! But will it still be considered as hacked if it was place in all of the files that has <head> tag? because there were many sites and many files affected.. even in the framework's system files......

Comment: If this is the case, then your hacker has access to all the files on the server, which is more serious than you think. Read through @Umopepisdn's advise again as it contain down to earth but important information. I can add start looking into logs and file dates to detirmine how and when the attack started.

Comment: Yes, it's still considered hacked.  Unauthorized access is required to change your web pages.  The fact that your pages are changed -- and have been reported as serving malware -- is enough evidence.

Comment: Thank you all for sharing your insights ! Will keep note on these.